# Deprecated function in CiviEvent error logging (Drupal 7)

Tags: civievent, drupal, civimail

Running Civi 5.10.4 and Drupal 7.65.

One of our staff reported that they received an error message when they tried to send out a mailing to attendees at one of our events, through CiviEvent > Email all participants.

She sent out the email at the same time that our monthly newsletter was going out (2500 contacts), and we have a limit set on how many emails are sent per hour. (Settings are below.)

[image: Mailer settings]

I checked Drupal error logs and found this log but I have no clue what it means:

```
Deprecated function CRM_Event_BAO_Event::checkPermission, use CRM_Event_BAO_Event::getAllPermissions. Array ( [civi.tag] => deprecated )
```

I'm thinking our staff member got an error message because she sent out the email at the same time that we had our newsletter queued for delivery, but haven't been able to find any confirmation of this (or any information on why her CiviEvent email to 12 people wasn't just queued to be delivered after the newsletter was delivered).

Would appreciate help on interpreting that error message, or modifying settings so that this doesn't happen again. I guess a workaround solution is to ask staff not to send emails out at certain times to allow the newsletter to go out, though ideally I'd be able to do this without affecting other staff member's workflows.

EDIT: The adjacent error messages are as below (with a variety of referrers, all 'page not found' errors):

```
sites/default/files/civicrm/css
```

Answer (score 1):

That message shouldn't affect your usage of CiviCRM.

A deprecated function is typically one that works, but is no longer recommended for use.  The message is only applicable to developers.

To take an example with a visible component: You may have noticed that CiviCRM has two different calendar widgets.  The older one isn't accessible to folks using screen readers (i.e. Braille or text-to-speech).  However, each date field needs to be converted separately - a lot of work!  Rather than do them all at once, we have both calendar widgets in CiviCRM, but the first is marked "deprecated" so folks are warned not to use it in new code, and to remove it from old code when they touch that section.  In time, that code will be removed - but for now, it works as it always has.

Unless you have an extension that uses this deprecated function, there's no action you need to take.  While it's unlikely you have an extension that uses this, you can double-check by searching your extensions directory for the text `CRM_Event_BAO_Event::checkPermission`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yeah there was nothing in the extension directory for that text - though that does leave the question of why the email didn't send and why it gave the staff member that error message (yellow window saying to contact your administrator for more info).

Comment: Is it possible that message was adjacent to a different error message?  If you have the accompanying backtrace (which should be in the log right above it) there might be a clue.  If so, edit the question to include it?  Also - consider upgrading, 5.7.5 has a known security vulnerability!

Comment: The adjacent messages are "Page Not Found" messages, don't think there are clues there unfortunately but have edited into the question. Also my mistake, I'm on 5.10.4!